# How to get this Yii Extension to display assets images?

Tags: yii

Yii 1.1.8

**Issue:**

I have a slidewshow (nivo) extension that it's more or less working but no images are displayed on the page and ALSO no animation or effects runs. I see the buttons placeholder texts, I can make next and previous, but no effects, or images.

**Scenario:**

The assets folder of that extension has the following structure:

```
assets/themes/default/default.css
assets/themes/default/arrows.jpg
assets/themes/default/bullets.jpg
assets/themes/default/bkground.jpg
```

On `default.css` I have the following declarations:

```
background:#fff url(bkground.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
(...)
background:url(bullets.png) no-repeat;
```

and so on, so pointing to the root.

here's the `publishAssets()` on this extension:

```
$assets = dirname(__FILE__).'/assets';
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish($assets);
if(is_dir($assets)){
 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($baseUrl . '/themes/default/default.css';
} else {
 throw new Exception('Error: Couldn\'t publish assets.');
}
```

**Tries:**

I have already tested if `registerCssFile` was returning `NULL`, it isn't. So, I believe the `default.css` is correctly registered.

I have checked if those files appears on public_html/assets folder, and they do appear on:

`public_html/assets/randomhash/themes/default/default.css` (and so on...)

To even make sure of it, I checked the publish method on Yii guts and:

```
publish($path,$hashByName=false,$level=-1,$forceCopy=false)
```

`level=-1` means publish all subdirectories and files so, ok there as well.

So the assets are being published.

**Question:**

I don't know where to look more, in order to find why do those images don't appear while the extension works fine (but without them).

Can anyone give me a clue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the `default.css` file apppear inside `<head>`?

Comment: Yes it is. And if I click on it, I get the desired file.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS can simply refer to images with url(../images/bkground.jpg) without needing to know the value of asset hash.

Comment: Do you mean can't instead of can ? If that's the case, then, why not? I mean, I don't have a complex path. `url(imagehere.jpg)`. The css is living on the same folder as the images it calls... can that be due to the way `registerCssFile` works... I will check it out.

Comment: The paths to images in CSS files (like background-url) are always referenced relative to the CSS file. Try to use url(default/bkground.jpg).

Comment: If they are related to the css file, since the css file is living on the same directory as the images, the images should appear, or I'm I wrong? Still I tried what you said, no images. I even tried with the absolute path as well (including the hash). No dice. :(

Comment: You are right. Check that bkground.jpg (default/bkground.jpg) is located into your public_html/assets/randomhash/themes directory.

Comment: And it's accessible from the browser http://yourdomain/assets/randomhash/themes/bkground.jpg ?  Try to clean cache, restart browser and web server.

Comment: Yes it is. I checked using the following syntax: `<img src="/assets/acda762/themes/default/bkground.jpg" />` placed on my view file, and the image did appear. And by doing as you said worked as well.

Comment: If css file and image file are available at /assets/acda762/themes/default/ and you set url(bkground.jpg) maybe problem is in css styles which rewrite your original css class. Or your div is not visible.

Comment: I will turn my attention to the client side of things as you suggested. And reply back if any progress some hours from now. Thanks for your walkthrough. :)

Comment: I check and re-check the client side. No look. I'm clearly looking on the wrong spot. And the worst part is, I don't even know where the problem lies.

Comment: I created simple example http://www.artcradle.com/mem/test.html Everything works fine, if css/image files are available the issue with css rules or js code.

Comment: It was something related with the script in question. The javascript classes that should be present. Thanks a million Valery.